# ubuntu18.04 srart with err log: R8169 unknown chip XID 641, i cannot connect to the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, ethernet

when i start my machine， i can not connect to the internet， here is some information about my machine：
cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

uname -r :

```
5.4.0-105-generic
```

ls pci:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8125 (rev 05)
```

i check the log，and here is the errmsg：

```
R8169 unknown chip XID 641
```

can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the search engine of your choice you should find plenty of posts covering this error message and resolution options. Use a more recent kernel from 5.9 or install r8125 vendor driver from Realtek.

Comment: i did try to install r8125 vendor driver from Realtek. However, everytime i restart my machine, the driver seems to lost, it can not connect to the internet again unless i install driver manually again. i download the driver package ,and run the auto.sh to install the driver.